# scala sortWith: negative numbers are not getting sorted

Tags: scala

```
val reslist = List(200.0,-100.00,50.80,-400.83, 800.003,-6.513214114672146E85, -1.2425461624057028E86, -4.7624471630469706E86, -3.6046499228286203E86, 0.0, -8.833653923554989E85, 0.000, -4.795843631190487E85, -5.34142100270833E86, -3.48087737474366E85, -2.811146396971388E86, -6.923235225460886E86, -6.513214114672146E85, 0.00000, -1.2425461624057028E86, -7.073704018243951E85, -9.633244016491059E86, -1.1418901590222212E86, -2.115257701350766E86, -1.1418901590222212E86, -3.48087737474366E85,-1.0676381955303372E86,500.56, 2.900556,400.56,-48956.00,4509.0005); 

val weightlistzi = reslist.zipWithIndex 
// List((200.0,0), (-100.0,1), (50.8,2), (-400.83,3), (800.003,4), (-6.513214114672146E85,5), (-1.2425461624057028E86,6), (-4.7624471630469706E86,7), (-3.6046499228286203E86,8), (0.0,9), (-8.833653923554989E85,10), (0.0,11), (-4.795843631190487E85,12), (-5.34142100270833E86,13), (-3.48087737474366E85,14), (-2.811146396971388E86,15), (-6.923235225460886E86,16), (-6.513214114672146E85,17), (0.0,18), (-1.2425461624057028E86,19), (-7.073704018243951E85,20), (-9.633244016491059E86,21), (-1.1418901590222212E86,22), (-2.115257701350766E86,23), (-1.1418901590222212E86,24), (-3.48087737474366E85,25), (-1.0676381955303372E86,26), (500.56,27), (2.900556,28), (400.56,29), (-48956.0,30), (4509.0005,31)) 

// I am sorting it here.
val resultlist = weightlistzi.sortWith { (x: (Double,Int), y: (Double,Int)) => x._1 > y._1 }
```

Here is the resulting list. As you can see, -100.0, -400.83, -48956.0 are occurring before -3 and the rest....

```
// List[(Double, Int)] = List((4509.0005,31), (800.003,4), (500.56,27), (400.56,29), (200.0,0), (50.8,2), (2.900556,28), (0.0,9), (0.0,11), (0.0,18), (-100.0,1), (-400.83,3), (-48956.0,30), (-3.48087737474366E85,14), (-3.48087737474366E85,25), (-4.795843631190487E85,12), (-6.513214114672146E85,5), (-6.513214114672146E85,17), (-7.073704018243951E85,20), (-8.833653923554989E85,10), (-1.0676381955303372E86,26), (-1.1418901590222212E86,22), (-1.1418901590222212E86,24), (-1.2425461624057028E86,6), (-1.2425461624057028E86,19), (-2.115257701350766E86,23), (-2.811146396971388E86,15), (-3.6046499228286203E86,8), (-4.7624471630469706E86,7), (-5.34142100270833E86,13), (-6.923235225460886E86,16), (-9.633244016491059E86,21))
```

Answer (score 7):

There is `E` character in your numbers. This is [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

`-1.1E86` means `-1.1 * (10^86)`. And `-1.1 * (10^86)` is less than `-400.83` (`-4.0083 * 10^2`).